# Ironpython 2.6.1 on Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, ironpython

I am trying to integrate IronPython in my Silverlight application but am unable to do so. After downloading the binaries, every time I try to add the dlls as references in my VS2010 solution all I get is an error about them not being compiled for Silverlight. I have even tried downloading the source distribution, but cannot set the various projects making up the solution to build against Silverlight (the only choices I have are different versions of the .net framework).
As the IronPython website explicitly states Silverlight compatibility, why is it not working? Is there any easier way of getting scripting capabilities in my Silverlight app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use binaries from `IronPython-2.6.1\Silverlight\bin` folder in Silverlight.